# what's the code mean ---------"self(img,scale)"

Tags: python-3.x

In a class's definition, there are code --  "self(parameters)" I think self is the point of class, but the code like a function. my problem is that how to understand the "self()" in class of python

```
roi_cls_loc, roi_scores, rois, _ = self(img, scale=scale)
```

Comment: Please enclude the entire code. One line alone isn't making things really clear

Comment: `self` probably points to the class where this code exists. That class is probably callable. And this would lead to `self.__call__` in the class being executed with those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the class is a function-like class (also called a "functor" sometimes) that implements the `__call__` function. You can use objects of such a class as if they were functions:

```
class Foo:
    def __call__(self):
        print("__call__");

obj = Foo();
obj();
```

If you wanted to do that from within a method, you can use `self`:

```
class Foo:
    def function(self):
        self();

    def __call__(self):
        print("CALL");

obj = Foo();
obj.function();
```

Instead of `self();` you could also write `self.__call__();`, but that's just not as readable, so most people prefer `self();`.

Comment: I have understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

self could be class constructor and after creating class object there can constructor definition that is returning some value when you pass some arguments to its constructor